# Jupyter lab prompts for token; how do I find it?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I have Anaconda and just started Jupyter lab. I am prompted to enter my token or password, but I don't know what my token is. Do I have a token? If so, can I find it? If so, how?

Here is the output I got:

```
[I 2021-02-18 00:38:55.875 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[W 2021-02-18 00:38:55.881 NotebookApp] 'browser' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2021-02-18 00:38:55.881 NotebookApp] 'notebook_dir' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2021-02-18 00:38:55.881 NotebookApp] 'password' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2021-02-18 00:38:55.887 ServerApp] notebook_dir is deprecated, use root_dir
[W 2021-02-18 00:38:55.896 ServerApp] The 'min_open_files_limit' trait of a ServerApp instance expected an int, not the NoneType None.
[I 2021-02-18 00:38:55.937 ServerApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 2021-02-18 00:38:55.938 ServerApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 2021-02-18 00:38:55.939 ServerApp] The port 8890 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 2021-02-18 00:38:55.939 ServerApp] The port 8891 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 2021-02-18 00:38:55.962 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2021-02-18 00:38:55.962 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 2021-02-18 00:38:55.965 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2021-02-18 00:38:56.457 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2021-02-18 00:38:56.457 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: //...My Documents/Notebooks
[I 2021-02-18 00:38:56.457 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 1.3.0 is running at:
[I 2021-02-18 00:38:56.458 ServerApp] http://localhost:8892/lab
[I 2021-02-18 00:38:56.458 ServerApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8892/lab
[I 2021-02-18 00:38:56.458 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[I 2021-02-18 00:38:58.987 LabApp] 302 GET /lab (127.0.0.1) 1.00ms
```

Comment: There should be a line with your token on the console in the format `http://localhost:8888/lab?token=<token>`.

Comment: Thanks! I added my output to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find ~/.jupyter directory, this should be your home directory. This looks like you already configured your password (which replaces the token), so the output does not contain the token:

```
[W 2021-02-18 00:38:55.881 NotebookApp] 'password' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
```

Read more in [notebook token documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html#alternatives-to-token-authentication) and remember to follow [the migration guide](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators/migrate-from-nbserver.html). Use `jupyter notebook password` command to change the password.